# LLVM backend without jumps (no goto)

Tags: llvm, backend, llvm-ir

I need to write a LLVM backend for a language that doesn't support jumps (conditional or unconditional). The only flow control structures I can use are if-then-else and while loops (plus break and continue).

Is there any way (or utility) to convert from LLVM jump-based+phi-node based to this?

Comment: Isn't `if-then-else` basically a jump?

Comment: @arrowd: What I mean si that the target language doesn't support setting labels and doing GOTOs to them, which is how the LLVM generated code works.

Comment: Do you mean your backend emits code in this language?

Comment: @RegisPortalez: Yes my backend emits code in a language that does not support GOTOs (only while loops and if-then-else).

Comment: Add an example of what the target language would look like. I wrote a language that has no explicit "goto" but when I emit LLVM-IR it uses `branch and/or phi` which ultimately gets compiled to `jmp` in the machine code.

Comment: @FrankC.: My target language are computer graphics GPU shaders: GLSL/HLSL. Shaders don't provide something like a 'jmp' instruction. The only valid program structure supported are loops and if-then-else structs. This is a problem because the LLVM-IR code emmited by the compiler works with branch and/or phi, which are essentially jumps (gotos).

Comment: I really love the question, which deserves to be better formulated. I'll try to give an answer in the next days (no guarantee of success)

Comment: As a startup, you can already remove phi instructions using an llvm pass.

Comment: @RegisPortalez: Thanks for your interest, I recognize that I should have formulated it better :)

How would removing the PHI instructions help?

Comment: It's the first kind of "complex" stuff you want to remove (unless you can emulate it in your language).

Comment: I assume you've looked at http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html already. It appears the task is to convert LLVM-IR to the language of your target which does not have explicit branching but only loops or if-then-else. I believe it is the backend task you would have to detect LLVM-IR `br and phi` and emit into their loop or if-then-else representation in the new source target. You will need to do some inferencing/interpretation of the LLVM constructs to rationalize the best translations (e.g. loop or if-then-else or combinations of both).

Comment: @FrankC.: That's what I want to do. But infering/interpreting loops from LLVM-IR is not a trivial task :)

Comment: "I won't promise you it will be easy, but I can promise you it will be worth it" :)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the relooper algorithm in the Emscripten, which was targeting LLVM IR to javascript, and there's no "goto" statement.

https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/introducing_emscripten/Talks-and-Publications.html